# Do word count by taking input from file line by line in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability

I have a source file which contains words and want to do typical word count, I am using something which converts to Array and takes into memory

```
def freqMap(lines: Iterator[String]): Map[String, Int] = {

   val mappedWords: Array[(String, Int)] = lines.toArray.flatMap((l: String) => l.split(delimiter).map((word: String) => (word, 1)))

   val frequencies = mappedWords.groupBy((e) => e._1).map { case (key, elements) => elements.reduce((x, y) => (y._1, x._2 + y._2)) }

   frequencies
}
```

But I want to evaluate line by line and show output as every line is processed. How can this be done lazily and without putting everything into memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you don't want to put everything in memory, but you want to "show output as every line is processed." That sounds like you just want to `println` the intermediate results.

```
lines.foldLeft(Map[String,Int]()){ case (mp,line) =>
  println(mp)  // output intermediate results
  line.split(" ").foldLeft(mp){ case (m,word) =>
      m.lift(word).fold(m + (word -> 1))(c => m + (word -> (c+1)))
  }
}
```

The iterator (`lines`) is consumed one at a time. The `Map` result is built word-by-word and carried forward line-by-line as the `foldLeft` accumulator.

Comment: For a large file, would the efficiency be compromised as I understand map results are build word by word ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. The result `Map` is built word-by-word, but how else can it be done? Even if you were to load the whole file into memory (not recommended for a very large file), split on the whitespace, and then `groupBy(identity)`, that still builds the result one word at a time. It just hides some of the details. I mentioned the word-by-word procedure just to mark the distinction from the line-by-line processing where the intermediate results are reported. If anything efficiency might be improved as you aren't loading everything into memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for are scanLeft method. So example solution might look like this:

```
val iter = List("this is line number one", "this is line number two", "this this this").toIterator

  val solution = iter.flatMap(_.split(" ")).scanLeft[Map[String, Int]](Map.empty){
    case (acc, word) =>
      println(word)
      acc.updated(word, acc.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1)
  }
```

It's all lazy and pull based, if you execute   val solution = iter.flatMap(_.split(" ")).scanLeftMap[String, Int]{
    case (acc, word) =>
      println(word)
      acc.updated(word, acc.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1)
  }

`println(solution.take(3).toList)` this will get printed to the console:

```
  val solution = iter.flatMap(_.split(" ")).scanLeft[Map[String, Int]](Map.empty){
case (acc, word) =>
  println(word)
  acc.updated(word, acc.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1)
```

}

```
this
is
line
number
one
List(Map(), Map(this -> 1), Map(this -> 1, is -> 1), Map(this -> 1, is -> 1, line -> 1), Map(this -> 1, is -> 1, line -> 1, number -> 1))
```

Comment: In the scanLeft the Map is returning a new map every time ?

Comment: What you get back is an lazy iterator of Map[String, Int]. It starts with a zero element, an empty map, and then it has subsequent states. So it's like a foldLeft, that stores all intermediate states.